# How to get qql expression from String

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, template-literals, tagged-templates

I have a String variable with GraphQL query. I want to write function which will return this the gql tag. Could you help me to write it. For example:

Input:

```
let input = `query { employee { id surname } }`;
```

Output:

```
let output = gql`query { employee { id surname } }`;

const getTagFromString = (input) => {  ?????   };

let output = getTagFromString(input);

useQuery(output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
let input = "query { employee { id surname } }";
let output = gql([input]);

useQuery(output);
```